# Dupclicator - Fatal error on WordPress login tests! SCRIPT FILE TEST, how to fix?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, migration, code-duplication

I use duplicator plugin for migration, as usually, and now I have this issue. I can't login too. It's not a hosting issue, I tried on one hosting and now try on Openserver, the issue is the same.
I don't see my problem in [documentation](https://snapcreek.com/duplicator/docs/faqs-tech/)  [image]

It's a first time like that, maybe someone already faced it?

Comment: This happens when the wp-login.php file goes missing. You can just simply download the latest WordPress or the same WordPress version as yours and copy and paste the wp-login.php file in mini.luna folder. It'll solve the issue.

Comment: unfortunately didn't help, it asked more and more files, all folders wp-include, wp-admin, no plugins inside. maybe it's because of itheme security? or something else damages the archive. I tried to make another package - still like that

Comment: Check the files and folder permissions once.